# using EF migrations with SQL Server (Not express/localdb)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

New to EF.
Am using code first but created from an initial database.
First issue is when I added a foreign key to the model After executing add-migrations from the console it created migrations to create the entire tables rather than just adding the foreign keys to the existing tables using `AddForeignKey(....),`
And when I try to update-database it tries to create a localdb database under and i get the error 

`Directory lookup for the file "C:\src\Project\App_Data\TheDatabase.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.`
Which kind of makes sense because i'm not using sqlexpress.
It seems as though I need some configuration to coax it into action.
Any useful advice would be welcome.

Comment: Can you just do a quick check? USe as default connection factory System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory rather than LocalDb.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although maybe this is more of a workaround
I did change the connection factory but it did nothing. Still tries to use App_Data folder and looks for an MDF there.
I found a work around though. The package manager lets you override the connection string so i just did that and it works fine. 
As for the other part of my question regarding why it was trying to create the tables. What I needed to do first it use the Add-Migration with -IgnoreChanges and update-database will then store an initial blank migration so from then on, any changes you make will be just those incremental ones I was referring to.
Here was the link for that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
Thanks to those who offered help.

Answer (score -1):

Hope [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) helps. Basically, EF needs your first snapshot of your database to create the model classes as the initial state, after that you can add migrations.

If it doesn't help, can you post your connection string and number of migrations your have?

Comment: Thanks for that. I followed the reverse engineer steps of this process.
So all i am doing is following steps to modify my reverse engineered model and create the migrations to be applied. This is where im not seeing what im expecting.
Here is my connection string from web.config.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TheData" connectionString="data source=(local);initial catalog=&quot;The Data&quot;;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Also noticed this. Would this screw things up if im not using localdb?

Comment: <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

Comment: Of course you can use System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory rather than System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, if you can do it and post the results.